# Trying to loop across a vector of data frames

Tags: r, loops

What have I done wrong here. Im trying to apply the following 2 lines to a loop using a vector of data frame names

```
df[5:length(df)][!is.na(df[5:length(df)])] <- 1
df[5:length(df)][is.na(df[5:length(df)])] <- 0
```

namelist is a vector of 12 df names

```
for(i in namelist){
 i[5:length(i)][!is.na(i[5:length(i)])] <- 1
 i[5:length(i)][is.na(i[5:length(i)])] <- 0
  }
```

Variables 1:4 in all of the data frames are to be kept but I want the rest as a binary (na = 0 , else 1) but the size of each data frame can vary (obs and vars).

Does not have to be a fast solution as this is a small data set

Comment: A list of data frame names is just a character vector; you'd have to use `get`/`mget`/the like to get the objects. That said, this is a bad idiom; [just store a list of data frames from the start](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/4497050) and use `lapply`/the like.

Comment: you need to set up a list, with each of your dataframes as an element of the list. Then you should use `lapply` as @alistaire mentioned. That's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that generates a list of data frames containing uniform random numbers, and processes it with `lapply()` as proposed in the OP comments. Instead of using `is.na()` to set TRUE vs FALSE, we use `> 0.5` to create results data frames because data frames created as matrices of `runif()` values won't have missing values.

Note that `is.na()` can be used to set the entire output data frame to TRUE or FALSE values. No second pass of the data is required for `!is.na()`.

Also note that the solution randomly assigns the number of columns in a data frame, so one can see that the solution does not require knowledge of the number of columns in each data frame.

Finally, to illustrate how to process a subset of the columns rather than the entire input data frame, we include logic to bind the first 4 columns of the original data with the columns of logicals.

```
set.seed(95014123)
dataList <- lapply(1:5,function(x) {
     columnCount <- sample(6:10,1)
     data.frame(matrix(runif(10*columnCount),nrow=10,ncol=columnCount))
})

# recode to binary based on whether values are > 0.5
resultList <- lapply(dataList,function(x) {
     recodedCols <- as.data.frame(x[,5:ncol(x)] > .5)
     colNames <- names(x[,5:ncol(x)])
     names(recodedCols) <- colNames
     cbind(x[,1:4],recodedCols)
 })

 # count sum of TRUEs across data tables
 unlist(lapply(resultList,function(x){
     sum(colSums(x[,5:ncol(x)]))
 }))
```

...and the output:

```
> unlist(lapply(resultList,function(x){
+      sum(colSums(x[,5:ncol(x)]))
+ }))
[1] 27 20 22 27 17
>
```

**UPDATE:** Here is a solution that generates a random percentage of `NA` values and uses `is.na()` to create the result data frames.

```
set.seed(95014123)
dataList <- lapply(1:5,function(x) {
     columnCount <- sample(6:10,1)
     pctMissing <- sample(c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5),1)
     dataValues <- runif(10*columnCount)
     missingIds <- sample(1:(10*columnCount),
                          size=(pctMissing*10*columnCount)) 
     dataValues[missingIds] <- NA
     data.frame(matrix(dataValues,nrow=10,ncol=columnCount))
})

resultList <- lapply(dataList,function(x) {
     recodedCols <- as.data.frame(is.na(x[,5:ncol(x)])) 
     colNames <- names(x[,5:ncol(x)])
     names(recodedCols) <- colNames
     cbind(x[,1:4],recodedCols)
})

# count sum of TRUEs across data tables
unlist(lapply(resultList,function(x){
     sum(colSums(x[,5:ncol(x)]))
}))
```

...and the output:

```
> unlist(lapply(resultList,function(x){
+      sum(colSums(x[,5:ncol(x)]))
+ }))
[1] 23 16  9  1 17
>
```